# ¿Cómo ejecutar un método de C# a través de un archivo XML?

Tags: c#, xml

voy a ser más claro en mi pregunta:

Primero, tengo un proyecto hecho en Visual Studio (lenguaje C#), con sus respectivas clases y métodos, así:

```
public class rojo{
    public void metodo1(string data1, string data2){
      //contenido del método usando data1 y data2
    }
}

public class azul{
    public void metodo2(string data1, string data 2, string data3){
        //contenido del método usando data1, data2 y data3
    }
}
//Más clases con sus respectivos métodos...
```

En mi clase principal tengo un botón para cargar y leer un archivo con extensión .xml, por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <typeName>proyecto.rojo</typeName>
   <methodName>metodo1</methodName>
    <params>
     <param>
      <value>
        data1 para el método1
      </value>
      </param>
     <param>
     <value>
        data2 para el método1
     </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
<!--Otros bloques con otros llamados a otras clases y métodos de mi proyecto-->
```

Mi duda es, ¿Es posible que mediante la lectura de los bloques de mi archivo xml pueda ejecutar determinados métodos de mi proyecto referenciándolos por sus nombres con sus respectivos parámetros? Es decir, que en la lectura de mi archivo xml pueda detectar qué método se quiere usar y enviarle su respectiva data.

Espero sus respuestas sobre información, alguna pista o el tema en concreto que pueda guiarme en este proceso.

Muchas gracias por su atención y tiempo.

Comment: Claro, es posible. Revisa [Reflexión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

Comment: Busca información sobre *Dependency Injection* (DI) en C#. En Java existen varios frameworks que permiten instanciar clases en función de ficheros de configuración; me sorprendería que no hubiera algo parecido en C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el metodo estatico `System.Type.GetType(string typename)` puedes lograrlo. Solo tienes que pasarle el nombre del tipo con su namespace y luego buscar por el metodo utilizando `Type#GetMethod(string name)`.

Suponiendo que ya parseaste el XML, primero inicializa el tipo utilizando Type.GetType();

```
var classType = Type.GetType(xml.typename);
```

Luego inicializias la instancia utilizando `Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)`:

```
var instancia = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
```

Ahora buscamos el metodo de la instancia:

```
MethodInfo method = instancia.GetType().GetMethod(xml.methodName);
```

Entonces ejecutas el método utilizando `method.Invoke` y le envías los parametros correspondientes:

```
method.Invoke(instancia, xml.params.First().value, xml.params.Last().value);
```

Codigo completo:

```
var classType = Type.GetType(xml.typename);
var instancia = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
MethodInfo method = instancia.GetType().GetMethod(xml.methodName);
ethod.Invoke(instancia, xml.params.First().value, xml.params.Last().value);
```

---

Es bueno dar a notar que tienes que asegurar que pasar la cantidad de parametros con sus tipos correspondientes al metodo `Invoke` o de lo contrario lanzara una excepcion.

Comment: Bien, voy a consultar más sobre lo que sugieres. Gracias

Comment: method.Invoke(instancia, new object[] {data1, data2, 5});

Answer (score 2):

Voy a ponerte un ejemplo de cómo se llamaría a un método por su nombre usando [Reflexión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection):

```
string typeName= "proyecto.rojo";
var classType = Type.GetType(clase);
//creamos una instancia del tipo "proyecto.rojo"
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
//el nombre del método a llamar, que se obtendría del xml
string methodName = "metodo1";
//obtenemos un MethodInfo con ese nombre
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = instance.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
//Generamos los argumentos para el método
object[] arguments = new object[] { "data1 para el método1", "data1 para el método2" };
//Por último, invocamos al método 
mi.Invoke(this, arguments);
```

Comment: Genial, voy a consultar más al respecto, gracias por tu respuesta