# ¿Cómo hacer reflexión a un método de otro proyecto el cual es una referencia web?

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

para colocarlos en contexto y continuando el hilo solucionado a partir de esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo ejecutar un método de C# a través de un archivo XML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193020/c%C3%B3mo-ejecutar-un-m%C3%A9todo-de-c-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-un-archivo-xml)

Para ser más claro, con referencia a Web Service me refiero a que en mi proyecto de Visual Studio tengo lo siguiente:

[image: Proyecto referenciado al que quiero acceder a sus métodos por reflexión]

En C# ya puedo ejecutar métodos de un proyecto por medio de la lectura de un archivo xml, mediante reflexión, de la siguiente forma:

```
/*- clase: string con el nombre de la clase
  - instancia: instancia de la clase
  - method: metodo a invocar
  - info: lista convertida en arreglo object para invocar método que contiene 
  la data para la invocación
  Finalmente se invoca el método enviando la instancia e info*/

var classType = Type.GetType(clase);
var instancia = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
MethodInfo method = instancia.GetType().GetMethod(metodo);
object[] info = data.ToArray();
method.Invoke(instancia, info).ToString();
```

Hasta ahí todo correcto y funcionando en el caso de llamar a clases con métodos dentro de mi propio proyecto, por ejemplo, dentro de mi xml tengo:

```
<typeName>Proyecto.lectorXML</typeName>
  <methodName>lectorXML</methodName>
```

Donde la primera línea hago referencia al nombre del proyecto y el nombre de la clase, en la segunda línea hago referencia al nombre del método que deseo ejecutar, más abajo sigue la data que irá en el arreglo info.

Esta es la meta final de mi proceso, hacer ese llamado a otros métodos de otro proyecto por medio un archivo xml.

Ahora si, viene mi pregunta, en la primera línea de mi xml, ¿Cuál es el valor correcto en la etiqueta  para referenciar a un método de otro proyecto que es una referencia de tipo Web Service?

Es decir, lo que quiero es:

```
<typeName>Proyecto.PROYECTO_REF_WEB.METODO_REF_WEB</typeName>
 <methodName>NOMBRE_METODO_DE_LA_CLASE_DE_REF_WEB</methodName>
```

¿Es posible simplemente con el nombre que indico anteriormente o debo hacer algo adicional a la reflexión en mi código fuente de C#?

Ya lo he intentado como sugiero pero algo debo estar haciendo mal porque tengo la siguiente salida:

```
{"El valor no puede ser nulo.\r\nNombre del parámetro: type"}
```

Estoy atento a sus respuestas, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo has intentado? Que problemas te has encontrado? Por cierto, no entiendo muy bien el problema. Si quieres llamar a un webservice, no necesitas reflection. Si quieres llamar a un método, ya sabes como. Que significa _método de otro proyecto que es una referencia de tipo Web Service_?

Comment: Claro, ya lo intenté, voy a ampliar mi pregunta y explico más detalladamente lo que me pasó

Comment: Listo, ya actulice mi pregunta, le agradezco el interés

Comment: Estoy haciendo una prueba, pero creo que en typename deberías meter algo como `Proyecto.PROYECTO_REF_WEB.CLASEREFWEB`. Puedes probar cual es creando un nuevo ws en el codigo con `var instancia= new PROYECTO_REF_WEB.CLASEREFWEB();`

Comment: Creo que luego puedes tener otro problema, dependiendo de tu ws, pero lo primero es que puedas crear la instancia del ws. Como digo, en tu caso en `typename` debes poner algo como `Proyecto.ClientControl.ClasedeClientControl`

Comment: Ah muy bien, voy a verificar a ver cómo me va y te aviso, gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución resultó ser más sencilla de lo que pensé, estaba llamando mal a la clase por un error de interpretación, eso me paso al querer acceder a un método del Web Service desde mi proyecto usando *ctrl + clic* en Visual Studio, al entrar a dicho método, la pestaña me mostraba *Reference.cs*, así:

[image: Nombre clase al acceder al pasar el curso sobre uno de sus métodos en otro proyecto y dar ctrl + clic]

De forma confiada pensé que ese era el nombre de la clase que necesitaba, colocando en mi xml:

```
<typeName>Proyecto.PROYECTO_REF_WEB.reference</typeName>
```

De ahí la inconsistencia:

```
{"El valor no puede ser nulo.\r\nNombre del parámetro: type"}
```

Si bien el nombre del método era correcto, la clase que llamaba no era correcta, ya que *Reference.cs* supongo que es un nombre tentativo que le da Visual Studio a otra clase de un proyecto referenciado. Viendo detalladamente la clase que necesito obtuve su nombre verdadero

```
<typeName>Proyecto.PROYECTO_REF_WEB.NOMBRE_CLASE</typeName>
```

Mi error es perfectamente justificable porque estoy en proceso de aprendizaje del lenguaje C# y Visual Studio es una herramienta que también hasta ahora estoy conociendo, y hasta el momento me ha parecido interesante.

Gracias a eso pude corroborar que la reflexión también funciona para llamar a métodos de otros proyectos.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que ya has resuelto el problema, pero voy a ampliar la respuesta para contemplar una posibilidad que puede darse.

En principio, y como te dije en mi comentario, para instanciar la referencia tienes que utilizar el siguiente formato:

```
Proyecto.Referencia.ClasedelWebservice
```

lo que entiendo que era tu problema.

Lo que puedes encontrarte además es que para llamar al webservice necesites darle unas credenciales. En ese caso, se complica un poco mas el tema, ya que la instancia que creas mediante Reflection no tiene acceso a las propiedades.

En ese caso, la solución pasa por los métodos [`GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) de `Type` y [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6z33zd7h(v=vs.110).aspx) de `PropertyInfo`. Pongo a continuación un ejemplo que pone la propiedad `UseDefaultCredentials` de un WebService a true:

```
var classType = Type.GetType("Proyecto.ClientControl.ClasedeClientControl");
var instancia = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = classType.GetProperty("UseDefaultCredentials");
propInfo.SetValue(instancia, true);
string metodo = "NOMBRE_METODO_DE_LA_CLASE_DE_REF_WEB";
System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = instancia.GetType().GetMethod(metodo);
object[] info = new object[] { "PARAMETRO1","PARAMETRO2" };
var res=method.Invoke(instancia, info);
```